# using replacewith() div with new div on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have 2 divs here `products_list` and `new_products` which list a set of products running different queries.

I have a button `Link1`.Here i am trying to replace existing `products_list` with `new_products` div when I click on Link1 button. Please help me on how to javascript using replacewith() to achieve this using ajax.

**Products_list div**

```
<?php
//List products from database
$results = $mysqli_conn->query("SELECT product_name, product_desc, product_code, product_image, product_price FROM products_list");
//Display fetched records as you please

$products_list =  '<div><ul class="products-wrp">';

while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
$products_list .= <<<EOT
<li>
<form class="form-item">
<h4>{$row["product_name"]}</h4>
<div>
<img src="images/{$row["product_image"]}" height="62" width="62">
</div>
<div>Price : {$currency} {$row["product_price"]}<div>
}
$products_list .= '</ul></div>';
echo $products_list;
```

**New_products div**

```
<?php
//List products from database
$results = $mysqli_conn->query("SELECT product_name, product_desc, product_code, product_image, product_price FROM new_list");
//Display fetched records as you please

$new_products =  '<div><ul class="products-wrp">';

while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
$new_products .= <<<EOT
<li>
<form class="form-item">
<h4>{$row["product_name"]}</h4>
<div>
<img src="images/{$row["product_image"]}" height="62" width="62">
</div>
<div>Price : {$currency} {$row["product_price"]}<div>
}
$new_products .= '</ul></div>';
echo $new_products;
```

**Button**

```
<div class="w3-bar w3-black">
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 1</a>
</div>
```

Comment: For $product_list and $new_products you close a div but you don't open it. When you initiate $new_products you have $$ instead of $. During the built of $new_products, you use $products_list .= <<<EOT

Comment: $new_products =  '<ul class="products-wrp">'; should be $new_products =  '<div><ul class="products-wrp">'; Same for $product_list

Comment: @Gerard actually i wanted to have same css class products-wrp but products from different query need to be obtained replacing existing products with the same look

Comment: You need to put a <div> in front of the <ul>. The rest is fine.

Comment: @Gerard edited as you described now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To copy the content of one div to the other:

```
$(document).on("click", ".w3-button", function() {
  $("#products_list").html() = $("#new_products").html();
  // If you want to clear new_products
  $("#new_products").empty();
});
```

For this to work, assign ID products_list to the first div and new_products to the second one.
`<div id="products_list">` and `<div id="new_products">`

Comment: is it possible for a div class to be replaced instead of a element id?